# Multiplexer Question

Tags: digital-logic

I am asked to find when Z is gonna be high and which combination of ABCD does it. Book says it's 0100, 0010, 1001 and 1010. What I don't get about MUX is, for example, will 0001 will make Z be equal to I0? Will 0010 make Z be equal to I2?

I appreciate any... inputs. Ba-dum-tss!

Book is Tocci, 12th ed, btw.
[image: mux yay]

Comment: A [74HC151 datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT151_Q100.pdf) includes a handy function table which answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will 0001 make Z be equal to I0

**No**, this will make **Z** be equal to **I<sub>1</sub>**

> will 0010 will make Z be equal to I2

**Yes**

The first thing to clarify is the order of the bits. In your example, the MUX has **C** as the most significant address bit, and **A** is the least significant address bit. Note that **D** plays no role in the MUX data selection. It is used here as a data input to fulfill the equation:

\$Z=\overline{\text{C}}\mkern1.5muB\mkern1.5mu\overline{\text{A}}+\mkern1.5muD\mkern1.5mu\overline{\text{C}}\mkern2.5mu\overline{\text{B}}A+\mkern1.5mu\overline{\text{D}}\mkern1.5muC\mkern1.5mu\overline{\text{B}}\mkern2.5mu\overline{\text{A}}\$

and the inputs to your **Z** function are **DCBA**.

The MUX will output whatever is on its input, corresponding to the address **CBA**. In your case:

[image: Mux functions]

With a map like this, it's easy to pull out the \$Z\$ equation.

---

*edit* - a truth table for the problem is given in the 10<sup>th</sup> edition (found online as a pdf). This verify the results above:

[image: truth table]

Comment: Actually because D is not one of the select bits, 0001 means the multiplexer select inputs are 000, which selects $I_0$.  0010 means the multiplexer select inputs are 001, which selects $I_1$.

Comment: @immibis You would think so, but not according to the answers from his book: "0100, 0010, 1001 and 1010". These suggest DCBA, not CBAD.

Comment: @immibis The key is to treat the bits as the inputs to the Z function, not inputs to a mux.

Comment: the question specifically says ABCD... the question is wrong because 1010 (A=1 B=0 C=1 D=0) results in 0.

Comment: @immibis The question says "which combination of ABCD", assuming the OP wrote it verbatim. Either way, there isn't anything that says you have to strictly adhere to the order of bits in the text. The key information is in the diagram.

Comment: Oh, yes! That's exactly what I needed to see. I guess I 'got' how this thing works in the process too. Thanks a lot for everyone responses! If anyone needs this for future reference: Think about, for example, what the 'D' is doing in input I2. Nothing. That's why it's always gonna be a hot-line independent of D. The others are fairly straight forward! Thanks again, peeps.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

The combination of \$ABCD\$ that makes \$Z\$ high are:
\$ABCD = \{0010,\ 0100,\ 1001,\ and\ 0101\}\$.
(The left most bit is \$A\$ and the right most one is \$D\$.)

When the book says it's 0100, 0010, 1001 and 1010, the author meant it in reverse order. ie, \$DCBA = \{0100,\ 0010,\ 1001\ and\ 1010\}\$

---

> will 0001 will make Z be equal to I0?

\$ABCD=0001\$ will make \$S_2S_1S_0=000\$ hence \$Z=I_0\$
\$DCBA=0001\$ will make \$S_2S_1S_0=001\$ hence \$Z=I_1\$

> Will 0010 make Z be equal to I2?

\$ABCD=0010\$ will make \$S_2S_1S_0=100\$ hence \$Z=I_4\$
\$DCBA=0010\$ will make \$S_2S_1S_0=010\$ hence \$Z=I_2\$

Read: [Multiplexers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer).

Comment: This is wrong. The bits in the problem are not ordered ABCD. If they were 1010 would not be in the solution set.

Comment: @BlairFonville Yes. \$ABCD=1010\$ is not in the solution set. When I wrote \$ABCD=0001\$, I meant \$A=0,\ B=0\ C=0\ and\ D=1\$. So \$Z=I_0\$ in that case.

Comment: 1010 is in the solution set, as stated in the question.

Comment: @BlairFonville \$DCBA=1010\$ is there in the solution set, but \$ABCD=1010\$ is not. Question has some mistake in it. To avoid that confusion only I have mentioned the order clearly.

Comment: Yes the question has a mistake, but your answer doesn’t point out the mistake - it reinforces it. The equation for Z shows the correct bit order, and the solution set demonstrates the order.

Comment: Okay.. Let me edit then..

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be rude, but it's even more wrong now.

Comment: @BlairFonville My bad.. corrected one. Let me know if it's still wrong..